# How to update the version of already installed GraphicsMagick in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, package-management, software-installation

On my server GraphicsMagick 1.3.18 is installed, but I need to update it to 1.3.24 latest.

How can I do it?

Comment: I only managed to find 1.3.23 for Ubuntu 14.04. Is that good enough?

Comment: you can compile and install it from latest source or stay with 1.3.23 from edwinks's answer http://www.graphicsmagick.org/INSTALL-unix.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I could only find GraphicsMagick 1.3.23 for Ubuntu 14.04. You can install it from the PPA at https://launchpad.net/~rwky/+archive/ubuntu/graphicsmagick using these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rwky/graphicsmagick
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick
sudo apt-get install libgraphicsmagick3
```

Comment: Also 1.3.24 is the latest release and it seems, it is only available as binary for Windows https://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/graphicsmagick-binaries/

Comment: Don't forget to also upgrade `libgraphicsmagick3` otherwise you will be stuck with the installed version